# Bootstrap 4 text wrapping for containers

Tags: css, formatting, bootstrap-4, styling

I am trying to get title text to wrap around a span object so far I have managed to get it to line up where I want everything but I just can't get the final part (the wrapping) to obey...I suspect it has something to do with the way that the text is in a different container but if I remove the container it upsets the rest of the formatting,

```
<div class="row px-3">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <span class="float-right d-flex ">
      <div class="align-self-center mr-1">Submitted by</div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn">User</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info"></button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger"></button>
     </div>
   </span>
   <h1 class="d-flex">
     <div id="title">A very long post title that needs to be long enough to see if the wrapping is working or not</div>
   </h1>
   <div id="body">a short body underneath the title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle of example code](https://jsfiddle.net/allw1994/6efszrkn/28/)

As the title suggests I am using bootstrap 4. Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: `I am trying to get title text to wrap around a span object` you mean what ? can you show a screenshot of result

Comment: If you look at the jsfiddle it makes it clearer, the text and the contents of the span behave like they are two boxes side by side but that’s not what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your issue, basically, your usage of tags is not proper.

`Element div not allowed as child of element span/h1 in this context.`

Check the fiddle link out, it solves your problem. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6efszrkn/47/)

```
<div class="row px-3">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="float-right">
            <div class="">Submitted                   by
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn">User</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info"></button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <p id="editor-title">A very long post title that   needs to be long enough to see if the wrapping is working or not sdjfs dakjsd askjdhas dkjashd asdjkhasd askjdhas dasjdasdkjasd asdkjhasd djkf dfuieywrbewrgew weruwe</p>
    <div id="editor-body">a short body underneath the   title</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would advise you to use W3C HTML checker.